# hd0 out of disk, grub rescue> when botting up off a USB drive ONLY with HP EliteBook

Tags: ubuntu, boot, usb-storage, grub2, hp-elitebook

I have Ubuntu 12.04 installed on a bootable USB drive. It works well with 2 laptops (meaning, laptops boot successfully off the USB drive). However, when I connect the USB drive to a HP EliteBook 8540w I get the following message:

hd0 out of disk
grub rescue>

Why does it even check hd0?? I went over all the BIOS options and couldn't find anything obvious to cause it. To be clear, I did change the boot order in the BIOS to USB device first.

I found a post (can't remember where...) that explained how to recover from grub rescue and the following commands work for me and allow me to boot off the USB drive:
set prefix=(hd1,msdos1)/boot/grub
set root=(hd1,msdos1)
insmod linux
linux /vmlinuz root=/dev/dsb1
initrd /initrd.img
boot

But I don't really want to type this every morning when I boot up my laptop :-(

Any ideas?

Thanks,
Tom

Comment: I'll be interested to know the answer to this.  I also have Ubuntu booting off USB - it works, but I do get that message